# How to retrieve session values on next page after writing session.Abandon()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies, session-cookies

in my button click event I have written like

```
  //delete session cookie
            Session.Abandon();
            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
            Request.Cookies.Get("ASP.NET_SessionId");
            //create new sessionID
            SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();
            manager.RemoveSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
            var newId = manager.CreateSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
            var isRedirected = true;
            var isAdded = true;
            manager.SaveSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, newId, out isRedirected, out isAdded);
           Session["id"]=21;
      Response.Redirect("cc.aspx");
```

on cc.aspx page load I have written like this,

```
int sss_id = (int)Session["id"];
```

but I get the value of sss_id as null instead of geeting '21'. please help

Comment: Why not use `Session.Clear()` instead? Do you have any specific reason why you want to destroy the session?

Comment: It results the same @Tobberoth

Comment: If you debug it, does Session contain "id" correctly when the `Response.Redirect("cc.aspx");` line is run?

Comment: Then you're breaking your session somehow, which `Session.Clear()` will not do. There's probably something you're doing in your later methods which ruin it. Try removing all of your code except `Session.Clear();` and `Session["id"]=21;` and it should show up fine in the debugger once the second command has executed.

Comment: when removing abandon() it works same

Comment: comment the Response.Redirect("cc.aspx"); line and try to print int sss_id = (int)Session["id"]; sss_id just below.

Comment: I have tried it. then get sss_id=20. but on cc.aspx ,its value is null @ray

Comment: Is "int sss_id = (int)Session["id"];" the first thing you are doing in cc.aspx. Please check if there is any Session.Abandon() or Session.Clear() before that in cc.aspx

Comment: there is no abandon/clear function on cc.aspx. dont konw why

Comment: you are setting "Session["id"]=21;" how come you get the print value as "sss_id=20" or is it a typo?

Comment: @ray sorry ,typing mistake. getting sss_id=21

Comment: Both `CreateSessionID()` and `SaveSessionID()` are documented with _"This method is not intended to be called from application code"_, so I wouldn't be too surpised they don't do what you expect them to. What exactly is your goal for using this code?

Comment: on cc.aspx i have to check  , string ss_id = this.Session.SessionID;
        string s_cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("ASP.NET_SessionId").Value;
            if(ss_id!=s_cookie)
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
@CodeCaster

Comment: I mean: why are you destroying and recreating the session, and why do you do it this way?

Comment: I have to create a new session id on each successfull login . for overcoming security issues @CodeCaster

Comment: Do you really need to set session values _before_ you redirect?

Comment: yes . I have to use this on next page. is there any way?